# Aligning two edge loops

Tags: modeling, edges, topology

I'm new on character modelling, from the tutorial videos, I realized that the vertices at the center of the eye formed an edge loop when selected through Alt+Right Mouse Click.
[image]
Another example:
[image]
I'm assuming that good topology should have the effect above.
But mine do not occur in that way, when I select the bottom edge loop:
[image]
When I select the upper edge loop:
[image]
The effect I want to achieve is:
[image]
However my edge loops do not connects as one. Could anyone points out the problems causing this and provide some solutions to it?
I will be greatly appreciate to anyone whom responded, thank you!

Comment: You mentioned some videotutorials. Could you add the link so we can see them? BTW, if there is no edge, there is no edgeloop. My guess would be they are just hiding the edges of the faces in the eye with a Mask modifier.

Comment: Here, https://youtu.be/EcjT-wGYVns. It mentioned during 8:30~8:50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is easy. Blender has no idea which edge loops you consider to be connected. In Blender, connected means there have to be edges between the verts. Your top and bottom edgelines are not connected and logical, implied connections do not count. The local symmetry of the topology of your eyes isn't picked up by the selection tool.

You can use Box-, Lasso- or Circle Select or you can add to the selection using Loop Select more than once, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>. If you needed a certain selection a lot, you could even assign the verts to a vertex group and select them that way. But Loop Select will not bridge gaps. Your topology is not to blame.

Comment: I think of that way but I'm not sure before, and thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can do this with viewport clipping:

[image]